# Django & gunicorn in docker-compose consume alot of resources ( Memory - CPU )

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have 3 containers that share the same code (WSGI - ASGI - Celery)
Everything works fine but when I check the docker stats `docker stats`
I found that WSGI consumes a lot more resources than the rest

[image]

The containers are deployed on DigitalOcean droplet without domain just IP

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/database/master/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ...
    volumes:
      - ...
    environment:
      - ...

  replica:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/database/replica/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ...
    
  replica1:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/database/replica/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ...

  backend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile_wsgi
    entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/wsgi_entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/backend/server/django_static
      - static_image:/app/backend/server/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - ...
    depends_on:
      - db

    links:
      - redis
      - db
      - cere

  asgiserver:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
    entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/asgi.entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/backend/server/django_static
      - static_image:/app/backend/server/media
    environment:
      - ...

    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - redis
      - db
      - cere
    expose:
      - 9000

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    expose:
      - 6379

  cere:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis/redis_1.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    expose:
      - 6380

  celery:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile_celery
    entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/celery-entrypoint.sh
    environment:
      - ...
    depends_on:
      - asgiserver
      - backend
      - cere
    links:
      - db
      - cere

  nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/backend/server/django_static/
      - static_image:/app/backend/server/media

    depends_on:
      - asgiserver
      - backend

volumes:
  static_volume: {}
  static_image: {}
  postgres_data:
  postgres_portal:
```

**Docker_wsgi**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim


WORKDIR /app
ADD ./webserver/requierments.txt /app/backend/

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
RUN pip3 install -r backend/requierments.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

ADD ./webserver /app/backend
ADD ./docker /app/docker


RUN chmod +x /app/docker/backend/wsgi_entrypoint.sh
```

**wsgi_entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

chmod +x wsgi_entrypoint.sh


until cd /app/backend/server
do
    echo "Waiting for server volume..."
done

until python3 ./manage.py migrate 
do
    echo "Waiting for db to be ready..."
    sleep 2
done

python3 ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput

gunicorn server.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --threads 4
```

.dockerignore is configured correctly and the build time is pretty fast
And I still don't know why Django is consuming all this

Comment: For anyone looking for a reason
The problem still exists now, but what I discovered is that this is due to database operations that return really large data that Django stores in memory, which causes this. And Django Debug Toolbar didn't help spot this early
I think that pagination and using sub-queries in prefetch methods will suffice